# altering type of attribute using yii migration

Tags: yii, database-migration

I have an existing database for web application developed using yii. Now one of the attributes in the table is of type int but I want to convert its type to timestamp in table. How I can achieve this using yii migration so that my web application is affected. I am using Mysql database.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

create a yii migration and modify the code

```
public function up(){
$this->alterColumn('table_name', 'column_name', 'new_data_type');//timestamp new_data_type
}

public function down() {
$this->alterColumn('table_name','column_name', 'old_data_type' );//int is old_data_type
}
```

then migrate up